# "sophisticated" is not appropriate in a research paper because it is an opinion?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Someone suggested me do not use "sophisticated" in research papers, as it shows an opinion, which is not objective.

Is that correct? If so, what are good alternatives?

Comment: If someone or something is generally regarded as sophisticated, you may agree with them. Describing Fred Astaire, his performances, his demeanor, or his attire as 'sophisticated', for instance, is commonplace. If not, then you can use it if you are prepared to justify the judgement by evidence and argumentation. If that's too much trouble, don't use it.

Comment: What is the context? What research field? What is the exact sentence? Who exactly was that someone (as his opinion might well outweigh any and all opinions voiced by random people off the Internet)? Have you checked a Thesaurus? In short: give us something, anything to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not something is sophisticated is not necessarily an opinion. For example, the quick-sort algorithm is objectively more sophisticated than the bogo-sort algorithm; *clair de lune* is objectively more sophisticated than *mary had a little lamb*. Such statements can be made because there real objective mechanisms for measuring the level of sophistication of an algorithm (e.g. time / space complexity) or of music (e.g. tonal complexity).

If the way that you measure sophistication is reasonably well defined, I'd say its fine to use it as an objective term within the context of the paper.